# ASP.NET Web API custom ReasonPhrase breaks self-host application

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

When self-hosting `ASP.NET Web API` service I want to use custom `ReasonPhrase` to provide more detailed information about result of requests. But when I provide it then client code fails to receive any answer at all, e.g. this answer causes `No Response` error on client:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(code) { ReasonPhrase = message };
```

The same happens when I use this code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = request.CreateResponse(code, result);
response.ReasonPhrase = message;
return response;
```

But if I use just

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(code);
```

then client successfully receives response.

[There's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794637/mvc4-webapi-reason-phrase) an answer stating that this is a Cassini's bug, and I also have found one mention of this Cassini's bug on the asp.net forum.

So what can be done to allow custom `ReasonPhrase` in Self-hosted `ASP.NET Web API` service? I would like to avoid using `IIS` to host this service if possible.

Comment: Can you use IIS Express?

Comment: @Smudge202 theoretically - yes, I have no restrictions on it, but at that moment it is more convenient to use self-host mode. But it looks like  this has nothing to do with Cassini of self-host, please take a look at my answer. Looks like there's no problem except localization.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Non-English text for `ReasonPhrase` (Russian, actually). When I've changed text to English then everything works fine. [Here](https://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/252140) I've found an answer that `ReasonPhrase` may contain ASCII characters only.

Looks like this isn't a Cassini's problem and I barely sure if this is a problem at all. But nevertheless it is upsetting we can't use localized `ReasonPhrase`.